# Parameterize link elements in QTP

Tags: performance-testing, qtp

How to parametrize link elements in QTP?

I have an order number in my application. I click on that number to find its detail. QTP save this as a link. Now I want to see detail of another order. I have parametrize the order number. Now QTP pick new number from datasheet. But as the link saved is for the previous order so that order is getting opened not the new one.

Answer (score 2):

If you use descriptive programming, parameterize object description through variable.

Example:

```
 [...].Link("name:=order" & intOrderNumber)
```

If you use mapping through repository, parameterize property value directly to datatable. You can find a very good explanation with screenshots in QTP help.

Answer (score 0):

Use descriptive for this. First check the property of that link changing every time with order number (name, display name etc.). Then use that property name like below:

```
B(...).p(...).link("propertyname:="&ordernumber,"index:=0")
```

The `index` is for unique identification.

Answer (score 0):

You can parameterize with descriptive programming or you can also parameterize from Object repository which I would not suggest. You can go to object repository Click on that button in object repository there you can find  + sign near by test object details click on that and add description properties "Outerhtml" and parameterize or use regular expression . You can also parameterize from Object repository. However, adding objects to object repository would only make things slow.  Descriptive programming is better.